# Ninject Intercept

Tags: ninject, interceptor, ninject-2, ninject-extensions

from what dll can i get the extension of Intercept ? 
I've added Ninject.Extensions.Interception from http://github.com/danielmarbach/ninject.extensions.interception
No luck there. 
Is there some sample working ?

What I need is to make an interceptor that will path through from WcfClient to WcfServer a different functions with different parameters , that way I wouldn't have to implement already implemented functions behind the WcfServer code.
So the the signature of the function I've already implemented is  -

```
public static T InvokeService<T>(MethodInfo MethodName, Type genericType, Type BlClass, params object[] ParamList)
```

What it does is activates the Method by BlClass and sends to it the ParamList .
I'd like to make an Interceptor that will dynamically fill the parameters while addressing the WcfServer side .
But first how can I get access to the Intercept extension in my ninjectModule?
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide :)

p.s. Tried out :

```
using Ninject.Extensions.Interception;
```

and:

```
using Ninject.Core;
using Ninject.Core.Interception;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the ninject projects are under http://github.com/ninject

You can find the latest pre-built binaries on our CI server at [CodeBetter.com](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt286&tab=buildTypeStatusDiv). In order to extend the interception mechanism, you need to reference the Ninject.Extensions.Interception dll and implement the IInterceptor interface or extend the SimpleInterceptor class.

-Ian

Comment: are there any working samples of this for asp.net mvc2 applications? Do I need to make the controllers virtual methods alos?

Comment: Anything you want to be able to intercept should be virtual. You will want to create a binding manually to add interception, or you will need to use the [Intercept] attribute on the controllers you want to add interception to.

Comment: Would it be possible to create CustomAttributes that act as an Interceptor? This way my logic is confined to an attribute that way I could add to controller or methods as needed? Would I then make these custom attribute methods virtual and add the required logic? The problem I have is I want the Intercepting method to be hooked up to other services or repository because my business logic is tied to the services or repository and I am not sure how to do this...

Comment: Yes, see http://innovatian.com/2010/03/using-ninject-extensions-interception-part-2-working-with-interceptors/ as I use two custom attributes with interceptors.

Answer (score 6):

the intercept() Method is within Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Infrastructure.Language.
I had trouble myself to find it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... Wonder how was it supposed to be found... Wasted last 3 hours searching for this.